CancellationTokenSource+CallBackNode Memory Leaks (10 MB/minutes)
I have console application for quartz.net operations.
Its basically settings serilog options, loading IJob implemented business logics dll's, creating token source then starting host environment:

class Program
{
    const string DllFolderName = "SchDlls";

    private static ISchedulerService _schedulerService { get; set; }
    private static CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource { get; set; }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetSerilogConfiguration();
        Logger.Info("Scheduler Service Started!!", "Program.Main()");

        LoadAllAssemblies();

        _tokenSource = new();


        await Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService(options =>
                options.ServiceName = "Test")
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerService, QuartzScheduler>();
            services.AddHostedService<QuartzWorker>();
        }).Build().RunAsync(_tokenSource.Token);
    }
}

I am registering the services. Scheduler interface is basically abstracts Init, Start, Stop operations.
public interface ISchedulerService
{
    Task Init(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task Stop(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

Implementation of ISchedulerService is Quartz:
public sealed class QuartzScheduler : ISchedulerService
{
    IScheduler _scheduler = null;

    private static async Task<IScheduler> GetScheduler(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => await GetSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler(cancellationToken);

    private static StdSchedulerFactory GetSchedulerFactory() => new();

    public async Task Init(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _scheduler ??= await GetScheduler(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(true);
    }

    public async Task Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_scheduler is not null && !_scheduler.IsStarted)
            await _scheduler.Start(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(true);            
    }

    public async Task Stop(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_scheduler is not null && !_scheduler.IsShutdown)
        {
            await _scheduler.Shutdown(true, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(true);
            _scheduler = null;
        }
    }
}

And the hosted service worker is doing start stop operations for .net console application.
public class QuartzWorker(ISchedulerService schedulerService) : IHostedService
{
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await schedulerService.Init(cancellationToken);
        await schedulerService.Start(cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await schedulerService.Stop(cancellationToken);
    }
}

There is the leak snapshot screenshot i got:

When i run the program for 1-2 hours its raises the 3-4 GB ram usage.
Its horrible for us,
I will take your advices or reasons to that and fixes.
Thanks for answers.
I have tested ASP.NET Core API to look for cancellation token and async operations leak. But ASP.NET Core api works perfect with managemenet.
But console application to use quartz operations not working perfect.
Let me know.
UPDATES:
There is sample of my DLLs doing jobs:
public abstract class JobBase : IJob

I am generating a library derived from IJob

In this way, by adding this library to the scheduler, I will write to the Quartz database and enable the triggers to run.

In this way, the desired things will be triggered at certain times.

In the constructor
I'm just initialising the Logger and Configs. There is no leak there.

I'm using a get response async that gets API results, but since it doesn't use instances, it said to mark static, so I marked static:
protected static async Task<T> GetResponseAsync<T>(string url, object body = null, string parameterName = "", object parameter = null)

This is a message generator for httpClient called in the parent method:
 private static HttpRequestMessage GetRequestMessage(string url, object body, string parameterName, object parameter)

A method that gets the report parameters from the api according to the type of the report and keeps them in the field, also overrideable for additional fields:
protected virtual async Task GetReportParametersAsync(string uri, AutoReportType autoReportType)

I mean, it makes sense and I don't see any leaks, please let me know if there are any.

Another method that extracts lists such as cc bcc and to from email send types:
protected void SetMailListBySendType(List<NotificationEmailSendTypeSurrogate> notificationEmailSendTypes)


static async Task<string> GetJwtTokenAsync()

This is a method that receives jwt tokens for api requests. It gets it once for each request.

Now I think I have explained the base class.

Let's look at other classes derived from it.

public class DailyUpsellingReportJob : JobBase
I defined a class that reports daily sales derive from base.

I override the Execute operation:
public async override Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)

So I did how it will work here. I returned the hosts foreachle and got the parameters for each host, got the mail types, calculated the attachments (I returned the report with the creation stream object.)

Example:

 async Task<NotificationAttachment> GetAttachment(string url)
 {
UpsellingReport upsellingReport = null;
Notif = new(){};

Notif.Document = new MemoryStream();
var dataFetched = api.GetData(blabla);

upsellingReport = new()
{
    DataSource = dataFetched 
};

await upsellingReport.CreateDocumentAsync();
upsellingReport.ExportToPdf(notif.Document);
notif.Document.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

return notif;

also in the finally block => upsellingReport?.Dispose();

This is how the work is done. There are many jobs like this.

I this memory stream side is leaking memory.

Now where is the part that leaks here? Thank you.



CancellationTokenSource+CallbackNode is created by CancellationToken.Register. It sounds like you're doing CancellationToken.Register regularly, but never disposing the IDisposable you get back? The normal pattern is using (cancellationToken.Register(...)) { /* Block of code which needs that registration */ }

@canton7 Hey canton, i am not using cancellation tokens in my business just porting them to .net and quartz.net services. What did i do is just creating source token for all operations. Is that not supposed to be?

Something in your code is calling CancellationToken.Register but not disposing the result, then. I can't say where those calls are -- they might be in a DLL somewhere -- but I'm pretty sure that's what's happening

@canton7 I have to look .net runtime and quartz.net source code then. Thanks for advice. I will let you know whats happening at the end if i find the breakpoint.

The problem won't be in the .NET runtime or likely the quartz.net source code. Do you really have no code of your own running anywhere?

Try to follow the DI setup from here in your program: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/using-quartz.html#configure-program-cs

There is not delegate about cancellation token call back function, my custom dll's has operations logics like automatic mails, creating reports and sending them etc. They are  all async Task operations in Execture context.
For example:
public abstract class JobBase: IJob{
public abstract Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context);
}
All logic in execute context for each job deriving jobbase class. All handled with try catch blocks and not using cancellation tokens. IJob interface is Quartz.Net package's interface for execution context.
So nope, there is no register in code.

@Magnus I will try brb.

I realize something new! @canton7
Hosted Service is not running any job in dll or job, but async operation and cancellation token still memory leaking for somereason.
40 seconds -> 410 KB async Operation / 160 kb ValueTask / 268 kb CancellationTokenSource.
Is there problem about RunAsync method? I dont think so but maybe?

@Magnus Dear magnus i have app.config that initialize configs on quartz. But your link is deafult implementation of it and its not compatible with my process. I already have manager panel for register jobs and triggers and their settings. I have service to consume this operations idlely. Quartz worker is just instance of job execute context. Jobs and other stuff already registered in database.

I reverted token implementation on service side and its leaking not that much now.
85 seconds snapshot => 3.5 MB
20 MINUTES snapshow => 4.5 MB memory usage.
Seems like fine.

Looks like you have a bigger problem: many ValueTasks which are being converted using AsTask and then not being disposed. That is probably the underlying cause.

RunAsync without cancellation token still leaking memory. Now testing sync host operation.
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService(options =>
        options.ServiceName = "Test")
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerService, QuartzScheduler>();
            services.AddHostedService<QuartzWorker>();
        })
    .Build()
    .Run();

I will let you know. If it is not leaking memory its all about host run async method problem.

Still leaking memory when triggers jobs while sync host operation.
I put short info of my dll jobs. Edited question. You can check it out.
Answers appreciated.

Problem like fixed:
I changed to ConfigureAwait(true) calls to ConfigureAwait(false).
Its like high memory usage on jobs fires, then its slowly drops.
Seems stablish, i will let you know guys.
